# Decrypt one cipher with multiple and independent passwords

Tags: hash, symmetric, hash-signature, multiple-encryption

Consider that an online shop subscribes an embedded external service for their customers. This external webpage is accessible through a clickable banner on the online shop.

On the subscription area of this external service, the registration form asks about the base url domains where the banner will be published:

```
companya.com
companyb.org
companyc.net
```

The purpose is to create a query string dynamically for the banner url redirect:

```
service.com?id=VO6Ny3WqBBIdZPufARCV10RPyY6nwQf37V8RClhJIlU
```

*The html code snippet to place the banner would be automatically generated on the client or server side and the form information never stored*

When a user clicks the banner, the server (Flask) gets the origin request domain (i.e “companyb.org”) and verifies with the query string if it is an authorized domain.

So:

- All the provided urls should create a single fixed size cipher.
- Appending more addresses should not impact on the size of the cipher.
- Each of the addresses individually should be validated by the shared code (that changes every time that any element of the domain list is added, removed or edited).
- The “encryption” (hash?) of the domains list should be preferably made on client side.
- The validation is naturally made server side (python-flask)

It’s all about thinking about managing a CORS policy without any storage since the validation is made on-the-fly solely with the information of the http request envelope.

Moreover, this cipher can also be encrypted by other means.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For the title, Encrypt the File Encryption Key (FEK) with a Key Encryption Key (KEK), now for each user encrypt KEK with their key which is derived from their passwords with a PBKDF.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that on every encryption of KEK I’ll get one different cipher. Therefore I’ll not get a single cipher that can be decrypted with multiple keys (BKDF derived keys)